# RecylerView scroll is not working on api 22

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to try my app on API 22 but it is working on my emulator, but I am facing a problem with  scroll list inside `RecylerView`, I can't see any error on my `Logcat`

This how I set it

```
mAdapter = new Sales_detail_adapter(getActivity(),detailList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

and here is `onResponse`

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObjd         = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray arrayDetail       = jsonObjd.getJSONArray("Salesd");
                            for(int i = 0; i < arrayDetail.length();i++){
                                JSONObject detail = arrayDetail.getJSONObject(i);
                                Sales_detail_model sdn = new Sales_detail_model(
                                            detail.getString("IdHeader"),
                                            detail.getString("ItemCode"),
                                            detail.getString("HargaItem"),
                                            detail.getString("PromotionID"),
                                            "0",
                                            detail.getString("Quantity"),
                                            detail.getString("HargaSetelahPromosi"),
                                            detail.getString("TotalHarga"),
                                            detail.getString("NoNota"),
                                            detail.getInt("Status")
                                            );
                                            detailList.add(sdn);
                            }

                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            mAdapter = new Sales_detail_adapter(getActivity(),detailList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                            progressDialog.hide();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            progressDialog.hide();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }eue.add(postRequest);
    }
```

here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".sales.Sales_detail">

    <TextView

        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/NoNota_label"
        android:text="No Nota "
        android:width="200dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/NoNota_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/NoNota"
        android:text="Default No"
        />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tanggal_nota_label"
        android:layout_below="@id/NoNota_label"
        android:text="Tanggal Nota "
        />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/NoNota"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tanggal_nota_label"
        android:id="@+id/tanggal_nota"
        android:text="2018-01-01"
        />


    <TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Outlet Code"
        android:layout_below="@id/tanggal_nota_label"
        android:id="@+id/outletcode_label"
        android:width="200dp"

        />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/outletcode"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/outletcode_label"
        android:layout_below="@id/tanggal_nota"
        android:text="M-MM"
        />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/penjual_label"
        android:text="Penjual"
        android:layout_below="@id/outletcode_label"
        android:width="200dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seller"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boby"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/penjual_label"
        android:layout_below="@id/outletcode"
        />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sku_label"
        android:text="Nomer SKU"
        android:layout_below="@id/seller"
        android:width="200dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sku"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boby"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/penjual_label"
        android:layout_below="@id/seller"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/posting"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Posting"
        android:layout_below="@id/sku_label"
        android:background="@color/primaryLightColor"
        />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"

        android:layout_below="@id/posting"
        style="@style/Divider"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/sales_detail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

how can I fix it, did I miss something ? thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: Can you share your layout file?

Comment: @FarukToptas please check it,

Comment: This is just a guess but pretty sure your LinearLayoutManager needs to be like this: `LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);`

Comment: Sweet! If I post my comment as an answer, could you accept it please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your LayoutManager like this:

```
LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the scrollview as parent view and inside the parent view use recylerview.